# How do I merge in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have two tables that I have to merge and I'm not too sure how to go about doing so.

Both tables keep a list of teachers and their teaching subjects. Each has a predicate along the lines of `school:teaches` and `college:instructs`, which mean the same thing. My task is to merge the schools together but as far as I am familiar with SPARQL I don't know how to do so?

So far I have

```
SELECT ?teacher
WHERE {
?teacher school:teaches|college:instructs :courses
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by tables. RDF data has no tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information about your data, but assuming `:teaches` and `:instructs` are only used to link teachers with courses, you'll need:

```
SELECT ?teacher
   WHERE {
   ?teacher school:teaches|college:instructs ?courses .
   }
```

Assuming `:courses` is the class of courses, and all objects of the triples you want to belong to that class, then you'll need to add this patters as well:

```
SELECT ?teacher
   WHERE {
   ?teacher school:teaches|college:instructs ?courses .
   ?courses a :courses .
   }
```